# How can I substring "val2" from a string formatted like "val1A-val2A~val1B-val2B~val1C-val2C", etc, based on the condition of matching it with "val1"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a certain SQL table I'm working on, there's a column that contains data formatted like:

"year-text~year-text~year-text~year-text~year-text~year-text~year-text~" and so on and so forth.

(***year is in 'yyyy' format***)

***(for example):***
"*2012-10000~2013-5000~2014-500~2015-50000~2016-100~*"

How, using SQL might I extract, say, the value "*50000*" based on having the year, *"2015"*

***Things to note/clarify:***

- The "-" and "~" characters can be trusted as delimiters. That is, they do not exist within any of the values or, of course, the years.
- No year exists without a value. In other words, if the value becomes blank, the year is stripped out, as well (In other words, the stored string will never have an "-" and a "~" right next to each other, such as 2016 in the string "2015-200~2016-~2014-1000", for example).
- The years in the string may not be in chronological order from left to right.
- There could be virtually any number of years (each with a value) in the string or, indeed, none, at all. If no year/value pair exists for the column, the value becomes *NULL*
- Please note that after each value for each year the character "~" is applied even if it is the last year/value pair. Any string value that is not *NULL* will therefore always end with a "~".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option which uses `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` to get the job done:

```
SUBSTRING(col,
          CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5,
          CHARINDEX('~', col, CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5) - (CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5))
```

In the sample input

```
2012-10000~2013-5000~2014-500~2015-50000~2016-100~
```

`CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5` would start at the `5` in the number `50000` *after* the occurrence of `2015`.

The term

```
CHARINDEX('~', col, CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5) - (CHARINDEX('2015', col) + 5)
```

yields the length of the number `50000`, which in this case would be `5`.

Comment: This answer is gold! Thank you! What's the best way to correct for the trailing tilde? Probably just a "-1"?

Comment: @VoidKing What do you mean by trailing tilde?  This should not be a problem so long as the year you are trying to find is there.

Comment: The returned result I get is (say the value for year '2015' is 10000) `10000~`. I just want to remove the final character (tilde) from each value.

Comment: I need to do this because I have to parse as a number and use in calculations.

Comment: I just updated my answer, it should work now as you expect.

Comment: I know this sounds odd, but with the correction (+4, instead of 5) it's still there. I tried something similar `(CHARINDEX('~', CERAnnUsage, CHARINDEX('2016', CERAnnUsage) + 5) - CHARINDEX('2016', CERAnnUsage) + 5) - 1` for the third argument of the SUBSTRING and I still get the tilde, as well. I can hardly believe it myself, lol

Comment: For some reason (show's what I know about 'CHARINDEX') if I change the `+ 5` in the same place to `-5` it seems to knock off the tilde. Is this what you'd expect?

Comment: @VoidKing I was missing parentheses, please try my exact updated answer again, thanks.

Comment: The solution I just applied only works if its the last year/value pair in the string. If I use it for year/value pairs in the middle of the string I get a leading `-`

Comment: Yep, that's perfect! Works marvelously. Thank you VERY much, good Sir!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help

With the aid of a parser and cross apply

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '012-10000~2013-5000~2014-500~2015-50000~2016-100~'

Select A.*
      ,B.* 
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'~') A
 Cross Apply (Select Val1=max(IIF(Key_PS=1,Key_Value,NULL))
                    ,Val2=max(IIF(Key_PS=2,Key_Value,NULL)) 
               From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Key_Value,'-')) B
 Where A.Key_Value<>''
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value   Val1    Val2
1       012-10000   012     10000
2       2013-5000   2013    5000
3       2014-500    2014    500
4       2015-50000  2015    50000
5       2016-100    2016    100
```

My Parser if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I was hoping to do this using just the query (as I'm using C#.NET, which is capable of supporting the use of procedures, but I am vastly unfamiliar with them). As such, I'm still giving you an upvote.

Comment: @VoidKing The parser can easily be incorporated into your query.   The declared string was just demonstrative.  If you expand your question with some sample data and desired output, I'm sure we can create a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substr and charindex

```
select  substr( charindex( 'your_val', your_column) + length('your__val') +1, 4);
```

in your case

```
select  substr( charindex( '2016', your_column) + length('2016') +1, 4);
```